# Body not extending to bottom of the content

Tags: css

My body is extending only to the bottom of my browser, but not to the bottom of the content. I need to have the background one colour, and the body content another, but i can't seem to make it work.

Here is the css

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
* html {
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
html {
background-color: pink;
}
body {
margin: auto;
max-width: 500px;
min-width: 300px;
background-color: orange;
}
#header {
background: url('http://placehold.it/400x400/0191C8') center;
background-size: cover;
height: 50%;
}
#updown {
font-size: 150%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LPXVm/

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/LPXVm/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPXVm/2/)

Wrap your content in a `<section>` (or `<div>` or whatever you want) and then give it the style:`background-color:orange;`.

Another alternative is to extend the closing `</div>` of `updown` and place it at the end of your content. Then give that a style of `background-color:orange;`.

But this will of course change the font-size of the whole thing.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPXVm/6/) - Second option.

Comment: In your second option you define #updown twice in the css.

Comment: Thank you so much, I used the first option and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

"I need to have the background one colour, and the body content another".

This doesn't make any sense. The "background" is the . The  is at the top of the DOM.

You should assign a `background color` to the `body`, and wrap all of your content in a wrapper div or content block then give that a different color.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LPXVm/4/